# SQL: How to get back only people who use exactly myspace and facebook, not just myspace OR facebook

Tags: sql

I am trying to return a tables `secret-identifier` which only has both myspace and facebook as there apps, not myspace OR facebook but currently I can only get the second option. This is my code so far

```
SELECT `secret-identifier`
FROM MyFavs__APP
WHERE app IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT app
  FROM MyFavs__APP
  WHERE `secret-identifier`='aha'
)
```

and the results i am getting is a huge list of secret-identifier's (that have either facebook or myspace) that includes the 4 that actually have both apps. how do i get rid of all the people using only either one of the apps?

Comment: Can you please show the table how the "secret-identifier" is stored in the table?

Comment: it wont let me copy and paste but it has the attributes secret-identifier(which is its key), app, since, hours-per-week, rating.
many secret-identifier's use more than one app and some have their app listed more than once

Answer (score 2):

you need to join the table to itself for both the myspace and facebook options:

```
create table  MyFavs__APP (
    secret_identifier int, 
    app varchar(16)
);

insert into MyFavs__APP (secret_identifier, app) values
    (1, 'facebook'),
    (1, 'myspace'),
    (2, 'facebook'),
    (3, 'myspace'),
    (4, 'myspace'),
    (4, 'facebook');

select distinct favs.secret_identifier
from   MyFavs__APP favs,
       MyFavs__APP m,
       MyFavs__APP f
where favs.secret_identifier = m.secret_identifier
and   favs.secret_identifier = f.secret_identifier
and   m.app = 'myspace' 
and   f.app = 'facebook';

+-------------------+
| secret_identifier |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
|                 4 |
+-------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I would prefer the `JOIN` syntax but the query seems correct.